# R Step function not selecting models

Tags: r

So I'm trying to use the step function in R with the Iowa, Ames data set, I can't get the step function to do anything.

I'm currently doing this -

```
step(lm(SalePrice ~ 1), list = ~upper(as.numeric(Garage.Area) + Lot.Area
  ), k = 2, direction='forward')
```

and that gives me -

```
## Start:  AIC=45082
## SalePrice ~ 1
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = SalePrice ~ 1)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)  
##      180241
```

I then tried this-

```
step(lm(SalePrice ~ 1), list = ~upper(
  factor(Neighborhood) * factor(Bedroom.AbvGr) * factor(Pool.QC) +  Bsmt.Full.Bath +  Bsmt.Half.Bath +  Full.Bath + Half.Bath + factor(Heating.QC)  + factor(Central.Air) +  factor(Overall.Cond) + factor(Overall.Qual) + Gr.Liv.Area + as.numeric(Garage.Area) + as.numeric(Pool.Area)
  ), trace=FALSE, k = 2, direction='forward')
```

But that gives me the same thing.

Why?

Comment: you didn't read the comments to your last question

Comment: ok...but how is that related to the use of the step function?

Comment: it shows you exactly how to use the `scope` argument which I am only assuming you misspelled as "list." Plus, your upper formula is malformed. That is also addressed in your previous questions. read

Answer (score 0):

If you define the saturated model (i.e. the model you want the forward step method to go to) then you can use this:

```
step(yourmodel, scope = ~. saturatedmodel , direction="forward")
```